# Calculate integral with dirac delta

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I want to show that
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left( \int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx \right) = \log(2) \delta_0$$
with $\delta_0: f \rightarrow f(0)$. My thought was to integrate by parts so that 
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left( \int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx \right) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left( f(2\epsilon)\log(2\epsilon)-f(\epsilon)\log(\epsilon)-\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} f'(x) \log(x) dx \right)$$
Would that integral then become 0? I know that $\log(2\epsilon)-\log(\epsilon) = \log(2)$, but I'm unsure how the dirac delta might come into it.

Comment: Make substitution $x=\epsilon u$ to get $=\int_1^2\frac {f(\epsilon u)}{u}\,du\to f(0+)\log 2$. So $\delta_0$ pops out only if $f(0+)=f(0)$.

Comment: What you write isn't true. This limit is going to be a NUMBER. You won't get a $\delta$ function(al). The left and right side of the equality are even the same type. Do you perhaps mean $f(0)$?

Comment: @avid19 How is it not true? Also, $\delta$ is defined as a distribution in our problems.

Comment: That's what I said, $\delta$ functional (a distribution is a functional on $C_c^{\infty}$). The left side of your equation is just a number. On the right side, you should either have $\log(2)f(0)$ or $\log(2) \delta_0(f)$.

Comment: What you wrote would be like writing $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: @avid19 Ah ok, I see what you mean. I suspect it is meant to mean $\log(2) f(0)$ but our problems are often not well-defined. Any ideas on how the solve the thing though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the hint given in the comments, let $x=\epsilon u$ to get:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_1^2 \frac{f(\epsilon u)}{u} du$$

Since $f\in C_c^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$ (or $S$. I'm assuming $f$ is well behaved because you're discussing distributions), we may use [dominated converge theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (I'll leave it to you to fill out the details. Why can we use this?) to get:

$$\int_1^2 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(\epsilon u)}{u} du$$

Since $f$ is continuous we may move the limit inside to get:

$$\int_1^2 \frac{f(0)}{u} du=f(0)(\log(2)-\log(1))=\log(2)f(0)=\log(2)\delta_0(f)$$